# Delete rows from table based on listbox selection

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I have lstPrev as an ActiveX Listbox. It has 10 rows of data. Once the user selects a row (single select) and presses the delete button, it should delete the corresponding row in dbTable.

```
Sub DelRows()

     Dim i As Integer

     Set i = ActiveSheet.lstPrev.ListIndex + 1 'to ensure column headers are not deleted

     dbTable.ListRows(i).Delete

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't `Set` an integer value. `Set` is for Objects like Ranges. To assign a value to an Integer variable, just do `i =`

Second, to refer to your Table, use `ListObjects`

This will work:

```
Sub DelRows()

     Dim i As Integer

     i = ActiveSheet.lstPrev.ListIndex + 1 'to ensure column headers are not deleted

     ListObjects("dbTable").ListRows(i).Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the guidance I needed :)